# Loading XML from a file on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, elementtree, file-not-found

What I'm trying to do is simple. Load am XML file using ElementTree so I can traverse it.

Here's the code:

```
_uri = '/news.xml'
self.root = ElementTree.parse(_uri).getroot()
```

And, the error:

```
file not accessible: '/news.xml'
```

From what I can tell, the parser can't find the document. Is there something I need to configure so python can see my site's files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably similar to:
[Read a file on App Engine with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630205/read-a-file-on-app-engine-with-python)

I.e. files that are marked as static are not accessible, but you can also serve it as an application resource file.

Comment: OK, I removed the static routing and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: This worked. path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], [filename]). It was a combination of the wrong path and the static route.

Comment: Could you please post the complete way of loading a file "myfile.txt" into a variable?