# File access error using cPickle on GAE - Python27

Tags: google-app-engine

I Have a test app that is configured python25 that opens a text fie in the root folder and is then loaded by cPickle.
the code is based on  [gae-nltk](http://code.google.com/p/nltk-gae/)
I have migrated the code to python27 and i get the following error in log console of development kit using the latest sdk v1.7.0 timestamp: 1337717865 
api_versions: ['1']

```
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in   dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\APPS\v2\knol_handlers.py", line 267, in get
kwds1 = Reply(tb1)
File "C:\APPS\v2\knol_handlers.py", line 108, in Reply
tok = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "site-packages\\english.pickle")))
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 592, in __init__
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\\APPS\\v2\\site-packages\\english.pickle
```

I have looked into configuration docs for python27 but I guess i am missing something.
Any help appreciated.
murray3

UPDATE = The file was available to be read when I moved it from root to subfolder site-packages. I upgraded to sdk version 1.7.0 and the file acess problem has resurfaced.
the file is not marked as static in app.yaml

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630205/read-a-file-on-app-engine-with-python. Probably you marked the file as static.

Comment: thanks skreft for the mind nudge, I created a site-packages subfolder in root, put the english.pickle file in there and it can now access it. I hadn't marked it as static in app.yaml Also I tried to make the folder name '\data' and it still wouldn't allow access so I tried site-packages and it done the trick, need to investigate the reasons further?

Comment: problem has resurfaced with upgrade to latest gae python sdk

Comment: can you update your comment with your current project structure and please reformat the traceback.

Comment: the english.pickle file is now in a sub folder of root called \site-packages

Answer (score 0):

OK lesson learned - be careful using so called boiler plate templates.
there was a reference in app.yaml that would include this as static.
I reverted to a basic app.yaml and problem is gone.