# GoogleAppEngine: How to read text file using python?

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine

My project structure looks like

```
flask-appengine-template/
                        docs/
                        licenses/
                        src/
                            application/
                                        static/
                                        templates/
                                        models.py
                                        settings.py
                                        urls.py
                                        views.py
                                        english.txt
                        libs/
                            bs4/
                         app.yaml
                         src.py
```

in my `views.py`, I have a function that reads the file `english.txt`

```
      for words in open('english.txt', 'r').readlines():
            stopwords.append(words.strip())
```

When I run this on `local environment`, I see error in logs as

```
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(13, 'file not accessible'), <traceback object at 0x10c457560>)
```

How do I read this file in Google App Engine?

Comment: Might this question be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2630205/1947535

Comment: `open('english.txt','r')` -> `open('templates/english.txt','r')`?

Comment: Try going from root of the application: `open('src/application/english.txt', 'r')`

Comment: convert the data from english.txt to english.py (containing a list of words) and import it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If english.txt is just a list of words, I suggest converting the list of words to a python list, so you can just import it.

If english.txt has more complex data, move it to bigtable or other database available to your app.

AppEngine is a very crippled environment compared to a standard VPS, I tend to avoid functions that operates over the underlying OS like `open()`.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and it worked, Thank you @Paulo

Comment: @Paulo By _crippled_, you mean performance-wise or w.r.t. api support? When it comes to reading off the filesystem, don't templating libraries like `jinja` do just that all the time?

Comment: This answer is quite old and somewhat outdated; the former "Platform as a Service" offer from GAE had several limitations compared to a VPS (for example, only pure Python libraries, limited I/O, etc). Nowadays I think they allow a kind of hybrid PaaS/IaaS approach where you can attach a network volume from GCP and do standard I/O in GAE.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use os.path to get the proper reference to the file path, something along the lines of:

```
def read_words():
    import os.path
    folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, 'english.txt')
    for words in open(file_path, 'r').readlines():
        stopwords.append(words.strip())
```

Hope that helps!