# PYTHON: removing POS tags from a txt file

Tags: python

I have the following txt file, which contains a POS ([Part of Speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging)) tag for each word.

> Needless/jj to/to say/vb ,/, I/ppss was/bedz furious/jj at/in this/dt unparalleled/jj intrusion/nn upon/in free/jj enterprise/nn ./.
>   How/wrb dared/vbn they/ppss

Is there any way to read the file without the POS tag, so the result will be:

Needless to say , I was furious at this unparalleled intrusion upon free enterprise .
How dared they

So, basically I want to remove any character after the `/`.

```
words = re.findall('\w+',open(input_file).read())
```

the above code will remove the / but the abbreviation such as jj , ppss still appears.
So, how to remove / followed by any character.

Comment: Will the file have any `/` that aren't a tag indicator? are the word/tag combinations always space separated? using `.split()` twice is the naive solution that may or may not work.

Answer (score 4):

Is this good enough?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Needless/jj to/to say/vb ,/, I/ppss was/bedz furious/jj at/in this/dt unparalleled/jj intrusion/nn upon/in free/jj enterprise/nn ./.'
>>> re.sub(r'/[^\s]+','',s)
'Needless to say , I was furious at this unparalleled intrusion upon free enterprise .'
```

This simply removes any text starting with `/` until it finds whitespace.

Comment: It doesnt work, coz the txt is in a list: newtxt = re.sub(r'/[^\s]+','',words) Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @user2152825 -- So you're passing a list to `re.sub`.  That doesn't work.  `re.sub` wants a **string**.

Comment: so, is there any solution?

Comment: what's wrong with passing a string?  `re.sub(r'/[^\s]+','',open(fname).read())`?  Why do you need `re.findall` at all?

Comment: It works finally, but I still have the newline tag like :  .\n\n\n\tPelham pointed

Comment: Oh, I need to work with list to count words frequencies, string wont be useful in word counting.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Wooble, you can do this with two splits nested in a list comprehension:

```
s = 'Needless/jj to/to say/vb ,/, I/ppss was/bedz furious/jj at/in this/dt unparalleled/jj intrusion/nn upon/in free/jj enterprise/nn ./.'
print " ".join(word.split("/")[0] for word in s.split())
```

output:

```
Needless to say , I was furious at this unparalleled intrusion upon free enterprise .
```

`s.split()` splits the sentence into its individual words. `word.split("/")` separates the English word (or puncutation mark) from its part of speech. `word.split("/")[0]` selects only the English word and discards the POS. `" ".join()` combines the resulting list of English words into a single string.

Comment: certainly, then it would be `[" ".join(word.split("/")[0] for word in s.split()) for s in myListOfSentences]`

Comment: Doesn't work on ``'/Needless/jj to/to say/vb ,/, I/ppss was/bedz fur/ious/jj'``

Answer (score 0):

This code takes account of Wooble's remark and of your need to treat a list of strings, afaiu:

```
li = [ ('//Needless/jj to/to say/vb ,/, '
        'I/ppss was/bedz fur/ious/jj at/in this/dt '
        'unparalleled/jj intrusion/nn upon/in '
        'free/jj enterprise/nn ./. '
        'How/wrb dared/vbn they/ppss'),
       '/Before/jj to/to say/vb ,/, /I/ppss am/bedz h/a/p/p/y/jj']

import re

def clean(s,r=re.compile('(?<![\s/])/[^\s/]+(?![\S/])')):
    return r.sub('',s)

x = map(clean, li)

print '\n\n'.join(x)
```

result

```
//Needless to say , I was fur/ious at this unparalleled intrusion upon free enterprise . How dared they

/Before to say , /I am h/a/p/p/y
```